# How to display posts with plugin (advanced custom fields) field groups?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, posts

I have a **php/wordpress** code (present inside **abc.php file**) as shown  below which displays images of particular size.

**php/wordpress** (inside **abc.php file**):

```
<ul id="list-thumbs" class="list-grid">
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>
        <li class="list-grid__thumb shows-grid__item">
                    <a class="list-grid__img-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>" tabindex="0">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                            <?php
                            $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() );
                            WORLD\Images\the_img_fit_figure( $image_id, 'list-grid__image', '(min-width: 450px) 50vw, 70vw', false ); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </a>

        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

The code above displays around 30-40 images from top to bottom with 4 images in one row.

**(a)** All of those images are featured image in wordpress associated with a post of **post_type hello-world**

**(b)** Every post has two fields, **Row View (in_row_view)** and **Column View (in_column_view)** coming from Advanced Custom Fields plug in. I am not sure if we can call those two fields as custom fields.

**(c)** **Row View** and **Column View** both are switch which can be enabled to **Yes** or **No**. By default, it is set to **No**.

**(d)** For Row View, I am using:

```
if(get_field('in_row_view' ) == '1'){   }
```

For Column View, I am using:

```
if( get_field('in_column_view' ) == '1'){   }
```

What I want to achieve is I want to display those posts which have **Row View** switch enabled to **Yes**.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php/wordpress code above so that it displays only those posts which have **Row View** switch enabled to **Yes**.

Probably I need to integrate this code `if(get_field('in_row_view' ) == '1'){   }` in the `php/wordpress` code above.

Comment: You just need to white a custom query, using meta fields. Then you will only fetch the ones you want in the loop - docs are here : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/#examples

Comment: @Stender I am wondering if you can give me pointer how I can achieve that. I've marked my question on bounty. Let me know if you need any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick/Sloppy Solution:**

```
<ul id="list-thumbs" class="list-grid">
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        // This will skip the loop
        if(get_field('in_row_view' ) != '1') { continue; }
        ?>
        <li class="list-grid__thumb shows-grid__item">
                    <a class="list-grid__img-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>" tabindex="0">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                            <?php
                            $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() );
                            WORLD\Images\the_img_fit_figure( $image_id, 'list-grid__image', '(min-width: 450px) 50vw, 70vw', false ); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </a>

        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

... the issue with the "Quick Solution" is that it will not render the desired "posts per page".  The easier way is to include or exclude at the query level with `meta_query` ... this can be done by grabbing the query "in flight" with the `pre_get_posts` hook.

**The More Elegant Solution**

```
function pw_filter_query( $query ) {

    // Your conditions for NOT applying the meta query ... use wp conditionals! :)
    if( !$query->get('post_type') != 'your_post_type ) { return $query; }

        $query->set('meta_key', 'ecpt_color');
        $query->set('meta_value', 'green');

    }

}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'pw_filter_query', 9999);
```

[Source Reference](https://pippinsplugins.com/using-pre_get_posts-modify-queries-meta-data-more/)

Comment: I tried with your Quick/Sloppy solution. It didn't work. On making one minor change in the code, it started working. Check the fiddle https://3v4l.org/4dGjg

Comment: Same concept as changing the != to == like this:

if(get_field('in_row_view' ) == '1') { continue; }